Signoz metric_name encrypted
I am trying to export some Signoz metrics using clickhouse and trino, when I perform querys to trino, the data is completly encrypted, even the metric_name is.
Maybe there is some kind of key to decrypt the tables?
Signoz is also known as open-telemetry

Hello, I am affiliated with SigNoz. What metrics are you trying to export and how are you exporting? All the metric data in SigNoz is plain text and readable and not encrypted.

Is the original data encrypted? What is the setting? Would that be an encoding issue?

Hello @SrikanthChekuri. I made the connection using clickhouse and then I connected it to a DL to consult it via trino. I am trying to export the metric_name using a simple sql query:
SELECT DISTINCT sm.metric_name FROM my_table.signoz_metrics.distributed_time_series_v4_1day sm

I do not follow your setup. Maybe create an issue here https://github.com/SigNoz/signoz with more details?

@MateoCherasco when you run that SELECT DISTINCT query, was the data already encrypted? If not, then this issue might not be related to ClickHouse.
